# Is charset=unicode UTF-8, UTF-16 or something else?

Tags: java, html, unicode, character-encoding

When encountering an html document with the following **Content-Type**:

```
text/html; charset=unicode
```

How should this be read?

I'm currently using the value of the charset as the second argument to InputReader's constructor in Java, eg:

```
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset);
```

This seems to read the document as UTF-16, is this correct? I've not been able to find any documentation about the charset name 'unicode' to know what is correct.

Comment: Does it throw run time exceptions? How does your browser handle it?

Comment: When in Microsoft Word for Mac 2011 you go to save as HTML, you get a file in UTF-16LE encoding containing `<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=unicode">`. So Microsoft Word may be the origin of the HTML file you are dealing with. I take it means UTF-16LE by "unicode", although if I convert the HTML file to UTF-8 and leave the `Content-Type` as is, it still opens it fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, this is wrong header, there is no such charset as "unicode"

according to [Setting the HTTP charset parameter](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset)

> any token that has a predefined value within the IANA Character Set

[These are the official names for character sets that may be used in
the Internet and may be referred to in Internet documentation](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml)

So, you need either tell developers of this service to fix error, or check actual content and only then suppose it as utf-7/8/16

Comment: And in practice, even web browsers take the incorrect charset `unicode` differently: Chrome and IE imply UTF-8, Firefox implies windows-1252 (your mileage may vary). There is normally no good reason to use UTF-16 (still less UTF-7) for an HTML document, so *probably* `unicode` is supposed to mean UTF-8.

Comment: And Microsoft's .NET framework treats `unicode` as an alias for UTF-16LE.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you export from Microsoft Word as HTML format and look at what it produces, it actually generates:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=unicode">
```

Reason I found this is that I had to produce HTML that would be opened in Word and display correctly in MS Word in Dutch, and when I used:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

MS Word would open the document with incorrect characters (the ë would show as weird chinese symbol), but when I changed it so my HTML said "unicode" instead of "utf-8", then MS Word opened up my HTML and showed correct Dutch characters.

So is MS Word once again doing things wrong? I don't know but that's what I have to output for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode is a numbering standard for all (less than 2^24) characters, there are several byte formats: UTF-8 (variable length multibyte), UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE (sequences of 2 bytes) and even others.

What you saw was wrong.